# Can a BtoB startup use product schema when our price is hidden with "request a demo?"

Tags: seo, schema.org, products, pricing

I am working for a startup focusing on b2b. I was wondering if adding any part of the from schema.org could be of any help to a company like us?

We actually already done it, but as we are not sharing the price of our products (it was replaced by "Request a demo"), I'm getting errors on Search Console.

Comment: Structured data doesn't help general SEO.   It doesn't help page get indexed or ranked well.  The only way that it improves SEO is when Google gives a "rich snippet" in the search results (that is makes your result look special with extra info.)   See my blog: [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/)

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller I'll look to your resources. French articles introduce schema.org as something positive for SEO

Comment: Stating product schema doesn't help SEO is the most ridiculous thing I have heard in months. Are there no professional SEOs on this platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can use product schema if your page contains a product. Having correct and useful schema on your page can potentially help Google understand the content of your page. However if you do not having pricing then obviously this is not a field you can use.